# How to limit NSArray output in NSLog

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, limit

I'd like to limit the output of an NSArray.

If my NSArray has, say 5 NSStrings in it:

```
NSArray *alphaList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"v", @"w", @"x", @"y", @"z", nil];
```

Obviously coding:

```
NSLog(@"%@", alphaList);
```

Will output all 5 NSString objects.

I'm wondering if there's a way to limit the output to "n" number of objects.

I was hoping there'd be a way to do this through adding a number to the format specifier but it doesn't look like that's possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: if you want you can make a category and you can override description method..

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. the solution i was looking for is posted below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"%@", [alphaList subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, n)]);
```